# 2 ItemsControl and one dataSource

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have 2 layouts, one for portrait and one forlandscape.

In each of these layouts I have an `ItemsControl` with a collection of `RadioButton`s.
If I switch from one orientation to another, sometimes a `RadioButton` is unchecked when it should be checked, so my collection of `RadioButton` contains no checked buttons.

Both orientations show the same data, with only a change in the layout.

Note the `IsChecked` binding: `IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">`

**Portrait layout**

```
<Grid x:Name="SymbolsGridPortrait" Grid.Row="1">
......
                        <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Disabled">
                            <Grid x:Name="SymbolsContentGridPortrait">
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SymbolsItems}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <RadioButton GroupName="SymbolsRadioGroupName" 
                                                FontSize="20" 
                                                Foreground="Black"
                                                Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                                IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                            </RadioButton>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
```

**Landscape layout**

```
<Grid x:Name="SymbolGridLandscape" Background="LightGray" Grid.Row="1">
.....
<ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Disabled">
                            <Grid x:Name="SymbolsContentGrid">
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SymbolsItems}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <RadioButton GroupName="SymbolsRadioGroupName" 
                                                FontSize="20" 
                                                Foreground="Black"
                                                Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                                IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                            </RadioButton>
                                        </DataTemplate>
.....
```

**ViewModel:**

```
internal ObservableCollection<SymbolItem> _symbolsItems;
public ObservableCollection<SymbolItem> SymbolsItems 
{
    get 
    {
            return _symbolsItems;
    }

    set 
    {
        _symbolsItems = value;
    } 
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class SymbolItem : Common.BindableBase 
{
    ....

    internal bool _isSelected;
    public virtual bool IsSelected 
    {
        get
        {
            return _isSelected;
        }

        set 
        {
           _isSelected = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**VisualStateManager:**

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state -->
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SearchBodyGridLandscape"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SearchBodyGridPortrait"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

                <!-- The entire page respects the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PortraitBackButtonStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SearchBodyGridLandscape"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SearchBodyGridPortrait"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
```

Comment: We'll need to see the model itself. The most likely scenario here is that you are not raising the `PropertyChanged` event when `IsSelected` is being set, so the other controls bound to the property aren't getting notified that a change has taken place.

Comment: @NateDiamond - I've edited the post and included some code from dataSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the previous answer is still true and is something you should update, there is one more issue. You have set all of the `RadioButton` to be in the same Group! Change the Setter as listed below, but also create a separate group (via the `GroupName`) property for each of the Landscape and Portrait.

E.g.

```
<RadioButton GroupName="SymbolsRadioButtonsPortrait" 
    .../>

........

<RadioButton GroupName="SymbolsRadioButtonsLandscape" 
    .../>
```

Remember, you need to do both this answer, so that when you change one value it doesn't deselect all of the other RadioButtons, **and** the previous answer, so that the Models properly update the other group's control.

Previous answer:

With `BindableBase`, they have build a setter method for you, `SetProperty` (`SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value`).

Change your Model like so:

```
set 
{
    SetProperty<bool>(ref _isSelected, value);
}
```

This will cause the inherited `PropertyChanged` event to be fired, notifying the UI.

Comment: It is not working. I tested with debugger and saw when rotating the device, the IsSelected getter is called and returns true for selected item, but right after that is calling the IsSelected setter WITH FALSE VALUE for the selected item, so no radio is checked anymore.

Comment: the radio buttons being in a group the OS automatically uncheck a radio btn when another one is checked. Here is unchecking same element. Maybe the portrait itemControl has no radio checked, calls IsSelected getter -> detects one item is selected and somehow uncheck the old value which seems to be THE SAME object. That's because are 2 controls and one has no check right after rotating the device

Comment: I've added the visualState from the page

Comment: Perfect. it works...I'm an android developer and i'm not  so familiar with the windows environment but you just saved me :)